# When 2 values are the same, check which has a higher value in another column and return a text value

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, comparison

I'm using EXCEL 2010.

I have a table of data for when tasks run through a certain period of time. Tasks can run in early break, late break or no breaks.

Column B returns a text value signalling which category these fall into.

I need to then check, if 2 values return the same in Column B, e.g. B10 = FS and B11 = FS, then I need to check which has the higher value in Column D and return another text value.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is hard to know what your problem is without a specific example.  But it sounds like you want to nest a MATCH within an IF:  =IF(B10=B11, MATCH(MAX(D10:D11), D10:D11), [whatever you want to do if they're not equal]).  It would be easier to help with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an array formula (or certainly what it sounds like you need to do) Give this a try: (bear in mind that the ranges are set to my test range, so you will need to adjust)

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$19,B2)>1,MAX(IF($B$2:$B$19=B2,$D$2:$D$19)))
```

Remember to calculate with Ctrl+Shift+Enter